# HapiJS and mongoDB project scaffold

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hapi.js

Coming from SQL and other "regular dev" methodologies (Ruby, Java, ,.NET) I've been looking for a while now on a good HapiJS project scaffold using mongoDB.

**I can't find a one that really hit the spot**.

What is the correct project structure? What is the best way to treat models? and more...
I know there are couple of resources out there, but I can't seem to find a one that really explain and justifies these design decisions.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you want there is [hapi-mongo-models](https://github.com/jedireza/hapi-mongo-models) and [dogwater](https://github.com/devinivy/dogwater).  I am currently writing models for mongo with [wadofgum](https://github.com/nlf/wadofgum) as its extensible and have started writing [wadofgum-mongodb](https://github.com/simon-p-r/wadofgum-mongodb) but just early proof of concept at the moment.  With wadofgum you can combine your own validation, methods and database for modelling data objects which I find useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are some starters/scaffolds available for hapi.

You could look at these two for example - they both use MongoDB and provide a good starting point:

- [Frame](http://jedireza.github.io/frame/)
- [hapi-dash](https://github.com/smaxwellstewart/hapi-dash)

There are more on the official hapi website under [Resources/Boilerplates](http://www.hapijs.com/resources).

If you are looking for something like yeoman generators you could find these two for example:

- [generator-hapi-service](https://github.com/normative/generator-hapi-service)
- [generator-hapi-rest-api](https://github.com/aduis/generator-hapi-rest-api)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I did look at these... (They are on hapiJS resourcres). I was more into a dissent generator (Yeoman or otherwise).